# Input data -> javascript and ternary operator

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently learning JavaScript and I had a few questions as to what was wrong with my code. I'm trying to make a simple age check with the ternary operator and form data. I'm trying to make it so that when the input from the form is under 18, you get the message, and when it is over the button appears. Thanks!

```js
var userAge = document.getElementById("ageInput");
const continueButton = document.getElementById("continue");
function verification() {
    continueButton.style.display = (userAge.value >= 18) ? "block"
: "none";
}
 verification();
 console.log(continueButton.style.display);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
    <style>
    #continue {
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form >
        <span>please enter your age</span>
        <input type="number" id="ageInput"/>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <button id="continue">continue</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach an event to the `input`. In this example `keyup` event is added to the input. So on keyup check if the value is greater than 18. Note the use of `parseInt` and `classList`

```js
let conBtn = document.getElementById('continue');
document.getElementById('ageInput').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  let ipVal = parseInt(e.target.value,10);
  ipVal > 18 ? conBtn.classList.remove('disableContinue') : conBtn.classList.add('disableContinue')

})
```

```css
.disableContinue {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <span>please enter your age</span>
  <input type="number" id="ageInput" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<button id="continue" class='disableContinue'>continue</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, so I’m guessing that type=“number” on the input type does not define the data type in js but rather is just the way the Input works in html?

Comment: it will be of string datatype

Comment: Alright, thank you, I’ll try to implement this when I’m free.

Answer (score 0):

Add your verification to an event listener for the input

```
userAge.addEventListener("change", verification);
```

In this way every time user changes the input your app verifies if he entered number greater than 18. You might also want to check for NaN values. If you want to check the verification on the fly as he is typing use "input" event instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach a function to input's input or change event. Like below:

```
userAge.addEventListener("input", verification, false);
```

Try it.